# Finding if a song exists by the name of a given input text

Tags: python, python-2.7, spotify

I am working on an application which would allow users to enter some text as song name and another input for the artist name, and then will check whether a song exists that matches both the input parameters. I'm currently using Spotify's API for the same by querying for the song 'Get In The Game' using this endpoint:

`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=get%20in%20the%20game&type=track`

However, Spotify's API does not allow filtering the results using both the song name and artist name together. As a result, the above query returns a list of all songs that match the `Get in the Game` song title.

How can I find whether a song exists based on the song and artist name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [last.fm API](http://www.last.fm/api), specifically the [`track.getInfo` Endpoint](http://www.last.fm/api/show/track.getInfo). This lets you specify both `artist` and `track` at once.

On success (you could also request for a json response) you get something like:

```
<lfm status="ok">
    <track>
        <name>Shine on You Crazy Diamond</name>
        <mbid>cb20321d-ecda-4fc1-a32a-0439a096a1bc</mbid>
        <url>
            http://www.last.fm/music/Pink+Floyd/_/Shine+on+You+Crazy+Diamond
        </url>
        <duration>763000</duration>
        <streamable fulltrack="0">0</streamable>
        <listeners>256400</listeners>
        <playcount>1511578</playcount>
        <artist>
            <name>Pink Floyd</name>
            <mbid>83d91898-7763-47d7-b03b-b92132375c47</mbid>
            <url>http://www.last.fm/music/Pink+Floyd</url>
        </artist>
        ...
    </track>
</lfm>
```

when the song is not found:

```
<lfm status="failed">
    <error code="6">Track not found</error>
</lfm>
```